# Using mechanize with Python properly to fill out HTML forms

Tags: python, html, forms, mechanize

I'm trying to fill out "name" form from specific website, I am new to mechanize and i'm not really sure how to use it, I have tried a lot of solutions... But this is what i've gone by far:

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
import re

NAME = "whatever"

def login():
    Browser = mechanize.Browser()
    cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
    Browser.set_cookiejar(cj)
    Browser.set_handle_robots(False)
    Browser.set_handle_gzip(True)
    Browser.set_handle_redirect(True)
    Browser.set_handle_referer(True)
    Browser.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
    Browser.open('http://arkhamnetwork.org/community/login/login')
    print [form for form in Browser.forms()][0] # Tried to see all forms
    Browser.select_form(nr=0)
    Browser.form["cdf254f828f75d57e0320558987a137d"] = NAME
    Browser.submit()
    return browser
login()
```

and i'm constantly getting this error:

```
mechanize._form.ControlNotFoundError: no control matching name 'cdf254f828f75d57e0320558987a137d'
```

This is what i get from: `print [form for form in Browser.forms()][0]`:

```
   <CheckboxControl(visible=[*1])>
  <HiddenControl(_xfToken=) (readonly)>>
```

However in page source, Name of the first form was: `cdf254f828f75d57e0320558987a137d`

Question:

How can i fix this? Is there any other proper way to fill out forms in Mechanize?

Comment: You're using the _form_ name, not the _input field_ name.

Comment: i'm new to mechanize, so i'm not really sure how can i select fields, or interact with it, Do i use browser.field["Name"] = NAME ?

Comment: Once you've called `select_form()`, you can do `Browser.form["fieldName"] = "Value"`.

Comment: so for this example, should i do like this? Browser.form["Name"] = "Value"

Comment: Yes, assuming `Name` is the name of the input field.

Comment: so how can i get input field names? do they look like this? "name="bf9d29c8b71f23b93e1341428eb90035", i'm sorry but i can't understand difference between these two.

Comment: Most input elements use the `<input>` tag.  Try looking at the page source and see if you can find any of those.  (Lots of things use the `name` attribute, so you can't just look for `name=...`.)

Comment: I tried selecting form with inspecting elements, This was input of first form: `<input type="text" name="bf9d29c8b71f23b93e1341428eb90035" value="" class="textCtrl" id="ctrl_bf9d29c8b71f23b93e1341428eb90035" autofocus="true" autocomplete="off">` is bf9d29c8b71f23b93e1341428eb90035 input field name?

Comment: I've noticed that input name is changing every time i reload the page, Is there any solution to deal with this?, Is there any way script can detect form with known information?

Comment: That's unfortunate.  Mechanize allows you to select a form by its position on the page instead of by its name; maybe it also lets you do the same thing for fields within a form?  You might want to read up on the mechanize documentation.

Comment: Yes, i will check it, Thanks for helping me, maybe there will be some kind of variable that can be used to fill forms, like selecting them.

Comment: ok after browsing i found out solution: form.set_value("example", nr=0)